# Multiple data centers and DataStax OpsCenter

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

Multiple questions regarding DataStax OpsCenter. I am evaluating for our use OpsCenter 5.0.1

1. I am able to build a cassandra cluster using opscenter sucessfully. However, all nodes belong to one datacenter. How can I build a cluster with multiple data centers? I don't see options to supply that information while building the cluster.
2. When adding a new node to a cluster, can I assign it to a specific datacenter ? Essentially, does OpsCenter provide a way to edit value in cassandra-rackdc.properties at creation time?
3. Does OpsCenter offer features to automatically restart a crashed Cassandra node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opscenter does not support provisioning clusters that span multiple DCs (except for DSE Analytics/Search DCs) or managing PFS/GPFS property files. AFAIK it’s in the works, but I haven’t heard any estimate dates.

OpsCenter does not restart crashed C* nodes automatically since there might be a lot of reasons why node went down, and automatic restart is not always desirable. In the future OpsCenter will provide more information on why node had died that will help with making a decision on how to deal with the failure.